# Легитимность обновления других сущностный, которые не относятся к данному репозиторию

Tags: c#, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования, repository

Есть EF, который спрятан за репозиториями.

Есть один репозиторий, где после сохранения должны произойти обновления в некоторых других сущностях , а одна из них даже живет в другом контексте.

В общем, красиво ли в репозиторий тащить бизнес-логику или этим должен рулить какой-то внешний сервис?

Если не красиво, то как быть с транзакциями.

Comment: Какая может быть транзакция между двумя контекстами? Видимо, эти контексты нельзя разделять

Comment: Ну если вы сделали репы, представте, что будет если вы решите, что какая то репа должна будет работать не с контекстом и а с внешним сервисом.

Comment: UnitOfWork используй.